# How do you distinguish between two inline template in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

Is there a way to distinguish two different inline template and reference them individually?

For example

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- rest of template -->
  </script>

  <!--Post-->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h3>
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
    ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)">
      </span>
      {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        {{comment.body}}
      </span>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="addComment()"
  style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Comment"
      ng-model="body">
        </input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

    </form>
  </script>
```

I only know how to reference the inline template in html using

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

however `ui-view` reference both templates and can't distinguish between the two tempmlates, is there a way around it?

Here is some functional code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cafcf0765ea412635042

Thanks

Comment: In run block of the application, you can define individual templates by using $templateCache service like $templateCache.put('template1.html','<div>Hello Template</div>'). and reference them into $stateProvider.state definition or access them by $templateCache.get('template1.html') programmatically.